# Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@prodDebugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project

Tags: java, android, module

I added another project a tv version of my mobile project as a module to my gradle file but I am getting an error. Below I will are the gradle files and the error.

build.gradle(Module:app)

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.enoch.steramexotest"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
        }
    }
    flavorDimensions 'env'
    productFlavors {
        prod {
            dimension 'env'
        }
    }
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.2'
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.13'
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.13'
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.13'
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.13'
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.13'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
    compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.6'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.9.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.6.1'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.5.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:leanback-v17:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recommendation:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:preference-leanback-v17:27.1.0'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation project(':mytvmodule')
}

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

build.gradle(Module:mytvmodule)

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27


    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.mytvmodule"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
        }
    }
    flavorDimensions 'env'
    productFlavors {
        prod {
            dimension 'env'
        }
    }

    buildToolsVersion '27.0.2'
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:leanback-v17:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.5.0'
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.13'
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.13'
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.13'
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.13'
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.13'
}

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

Error
[image: Errors found]

Error2
[image]

Everything seems to work fine in the mobile module. With no errors. I am planning to create a separate module that mobile and tv can share but wanted to find out if anyone can figure out the issue

Comment: Just uncheck the offline mode in your gradle and try again